# Rescale y axis ggplot (geom_bar)

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is should be very simple question! 
I would like to make a barplot with errorbars and I'm using the following code:

```
ggplot(data = bars, aes(x=c("1","2","3"), y=V2, fill = names)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=V1, ymax=V3))+
  theme(legend.position='none')+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,10))
```

However, I have 2 problems: 
1. I would like the bars to start at y = 0
2. I don't like the ticks in the y axis. I would like numbers with just one decimal and less ticks.

this is my actual plot: [Bars with error bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG1aM.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem (if I understand it correctly) you can use `ylim`

```
... + ylim(0.2, NA)
```

`NA` leaves the upper bound free.

For the second, I suggest to use `pretty_breaks` from `scale`

```
library(scales)
... + scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=5))
```